# Need help for managing functions of a Tkinter GUI in a separate file

Tags: python, function, tkinter

So I am new here and this may be very basic but I need your help. I am new to tkinter and was building a calculator as my first project. I wanted the functions of the calculator in a separate file, but when I import them in the main file they don't seem to work. I think it's a problem with global variables but don't know how to fix it.

Here's the error and the code snippets:

```py
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AKHIL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\AKHIL\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\CS-project\calc.py", line 83, in <lambda>
    button_6 = Button(calc, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
  File "c:\Users\AKHIL\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\CS-project\function.py", line 8, in button_click
    current = display.get()
NameError: name 'display' is not defined
```

this is calc.py

```py
from tkinter import *
from function import *

calc = Tk()
calc.title("Calculator")
calc.iconbitmap("calc.ico")


button_1 = Button(calc, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(1))
button_2 = Button(calc, text="2", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(2))
button_3 = Button(calc, text="3", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(3))
button_4 = Button(calc, text="4", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(4))
button_5 = Button(calc, text="5", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(5))
button_6 = Button(calc, text="6", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(6))
button_7 = Button(calc, text="7", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(7))
button_8 = Button(calc, text="8", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(8))
button_9 = Button(calc, text="9", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(9))
button_0 = Button(calc, text="0", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(0))


button_1.grid(row=3, column=0)
button_2.grid(row=3, column=1)
button_3.grid(row=3, column=2)
button_4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button_5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button_6.grid(row=2, column=2)
button_7.grid(row=1, column=0)
button_8.grid(row=1, column=1)
button_9.grid(row=1, column=2)
button_0.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

And this is  function.py

```py
from tkinter import *

def button_click(number):
    global display
    current = display.get()
    display.delete(0, END)
    display.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))
```

Comment: You need to add `display` as a parameter to `button_click()`

Answer (score -1):

> I wanted the functions of the calculator in a separate file, but when
> I import them in the main file they don't seem to work.

The problem can be fixed.

In calc.py module:

On button_1 to button_0, add Entry widget command keyword button_click(Entry, ...)

```
button_1 = Button(calc, text="1", padx=40, pady=20, command=lambda: button_click(Entry, 1))
```

Do the same as from `button_2` to `button_0`.

On function.py module:

- Add parameter on `button_click` function.
- Remove `str(current)`

Snippet:

```
from tkinter import *

def button_click(widget, number):
    display = widget()
    display.grid(row=5, column=1, pady=10)
      
    #display.delete(0, END)
    display.insert(0, str(number))
    print(number)
```

Screenshot:

[image]